# HDInsight Storm Event Hub Spout only receiving 1024 messages

Tags: c#, .net, azure, apache-storm, azure-hdinsight

I have an HDInsight Storm Cluster (Default 60 Core setup)

I have used the template project and am using the latest jar dependency (0.9.
4)

Yesterday I was running the application and passed 20,000,000 messages through my event hub, without issue.

After adding a new bolt (I now have a different bolt receiving from the EventHub) I am now only receiving 1024 messages (exactly) every time.

If I delete my topology and redeploy it, it used to process all the messages in the EventHub, now it is only doing 1024.

I've deleted the Service bus namespace in azure, I've recreated it, scaled it up to 10 MU's and still only getting 1024 messages processed at a time.

All I can think is that this is potentially something to do with the receiver credits?

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/hdinsight/hdinsight-storm-examples/commit/e395891695e7032005a3a058c47d7f1aa36c22f0) for the Java spout on github you can see this line:

```
+eventhubs.checkpoint.interval = 10
+eventhubs.receiver.credits = 1024
```

and from [MSDN](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/event-hubs-c-storm-getstarted/) the explanation of the EventHubCredits is:

> The value for eventhub.receiver.credits determines how many events are
>   batched before releasing them to the Storm pipeline

It's as if I am only ever receiving one batch. I am currently submitting 1631 messages, more than one batch, but not enough for two batches.

[EDIT] 
This seems to be directly related to the "StormConfig.setMaxSpoutPending" setting. I had previously set it to 100,000 and this has been happening since. After removing the block of code (below) that configured this, and redeploying, it still happened. But when I add the code back in, and set the MaxSpoutPending to 500 I now only get a batch of 500 and no more...

```
//global config:
var topologyConfig = new StormConfig();
topologyConfig.setMaxSpoutPending(500);
topologyConfig.setNumWorkers(partitionCount);
topologyBuilder.SetTopologyConfig(topologyConfig);
```

[EDIT2]
I rebuilt the whole cluster in azure, and redeployed the solution without any of the StormConfig (I deleted the HDFS blob store as well, so it was a fresh install. I didn't delete the table storage, but I don't think that is used for the Storm Server) .. and I am back to 1024 (not the previous 500) messages, but no more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that your bolts are returning acks. The Event Hub Spout expects acks, and if it doesn't get them it will stop receiving.

Comment: Thanks Larry, this  was the problem. I had two bolts coming off the EventHubSpout and one of them wasn't acking the tuples it was receiving, thus I only ever got one batch.